# Integrating django - haystack along with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, solr, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I am trying to setup solr search engine along with the django-drf.
I am using drf_haystack for this purpose.
I am using the solr-tomcat6.But I am stuck and I dont know where I am going wrong.Whenever I perform a search via a get call I get no response in the django rest framework page.
I have done all the setup for the solr mentioned in this tutorial - 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04
I have also put my schema in the conf folder after obtaining the schema from

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

As for tomacat6 the default port is 8080 my settings.py looks like -

```
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://localhost:8080/solr'
     },
     }
```

My models.py is simple with the title as the primary key and Test is the model.It looks like-

```
    class Test(models.Model):
        title = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key=True)
        url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        brief = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'test'
```

I am new to using solr there may be a mistake in my indexes.py , i have shown it here -

```
    class TestIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
        text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
        title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
        url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url')
        price = indexes.CharField(model_attr='price')

        def get_model(self):
            return Test

       def index_queryset(self, using=None):
            return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

I have included the serializer in the views itself.Here is my views.py-

```
    class TestSerializer(HaystackSerializer):
        class Meta:
            index_classes = [TestIndex]

        fields = [
            "title","url","price","brief"
         ]


    class SearchView(HaystackViewSet):
        index_models = [Test]
        serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

and finally my urls.py looks as follows :

```
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register("item/search", SearchView, base_name="item-search")

    urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r"api/", include(router.urls))
     ]
```

and I am performing my search by entering this in the url : 
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/item/search/?title__contains=Asus

which is giving a empty dictionary.Please help me with my problem and maybe there is a silly mistake .

Comment: I got the solution.I was using django 1.9 and when I downgraded to django 1.8 it worked.